# Resize one widget inside a row widget in flutter while the other moves

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gridview, flutter-expanded

I have a row with a gridview and a rotatedbox in it. I want to change the size of the gridview, but when I change it, the rotated box moves down.

```
              Row(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      height: screenHeight / 1.583,
                      width: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: ColorConstants.barColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(40),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: RotatedBox(
                        quarterTurns: 3,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Flat White",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: ColorConstants.mutedColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Espresso",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: ColorConstants.mutedColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Americano",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: ColorConstants.mutedColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Latte",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: ColorConstants.mutedColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Cappuccino",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: ColorConstants.textColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: coffeeName.length,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        childAspectRatio: 100 / 100,
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return CoffeeList(
                          coffeeName: coffeeName[index],
                          imageUrl: imageUrl[index],
                          price: price[index],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

I want to resize the gridview but I don't want the rotatedbox to move.

when:
childAspectRatio: 100 / 100, (Default):[childAspectRatio: 100 / 100,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVYtJ.png)

childAspectRatio: 100 / 200,[100 / 200]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/keqeG.png)